# Android - Nullpointer Exception when clicking a listitem to show AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I have a listview and when I click on a item it should show a AlertDialog with Radiobuttons in it. But when calling the alertDialog, the app crashes. Logcat gives a NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                    int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    final AlertDialog levelDialog

                    final CharSequence[] items = { " Easy ", " Medium ",
                            " Hard ", " Very Hard " };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MyActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Select The Difficulty Level");

                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int item) {
                                    Intent i = new Intent(
                                            getApplictionContext(),
                                            MyActivity.class);

                                    switch (item) {
                                    case 0:
                                        String msg = "Alert A";
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MyActivity.this,
                                                msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        String msga = "Alert B";
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MyActivity.this,
                                                msga, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        String msgz = "Alert C";
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MyActivity.this,
                                                msgz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        String msge = "Alert E";
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                MyActivity.this,
                                                msge, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                    }

                                }
                            });
                     levelDialog.dismiss();
 levelDialog = builder.create();
 levelDialog.show();
                }

                else if (position == 1) {
                    String msg = "1";
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    String msg = "2";
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (position == 3) {
                    String msg = "3";
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, msg,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a function on `levelDialog` before instantiating it

```
     levelDialog.dismiss();
     levelDialog = builder.create();
     levelDialog.show();
```

change it to

```
     levelDialog = builder.create();
     levelDialog.show();
     levelDialog.dismiss();
```

But I'm not sure why you are calling `dismiss()` right there. If this doesn't solve it then please post logcat so we know where the `NPE` is. To be more clear, switching these lines should fix your `NPE` but `dismiss()` shouldn't be called right there.

**Edit**

Take out this

```
AlertDialog levelDialog=null;
```

and declare and initialize it here like so

```
       final AlertDialog levelDialog = builder.create();
       levelDialog.show();
```

and call `dismiss()` in your `onClick()` but use `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `levelDialog.dismiss()`

Also, its typically better to use `Activity Context` instead of `Application Context` so in your `Intent` you might change `getApplicationContext()` to `MyActivity.this`

Comment: Dialog doesn't show as `dismiss()` called immediate after `.show()` method.

Comment: @user370305 I know, that's why I said "But I'm not sure why you are calling `dismiss()`". Should fix the `NPE` the OP is currently getting but doesn't make sense to have it there

Comment: I changed it like you said, now it isn't crashing but it doesn't do anything when pressed. I was following this tutorial to accomplish this. http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.be/2013/01/adding-radio-buttons-in-dialog.html They put it like this `levelDialog.dismiss();   
                    }
                });
                levelDialog = builder.create();
                levelDialog.show();`

Comment: Did you take `dismiss()` out?

Comment: It works without the `dismiss()`, but when I select an option the dialog is still there and I should dismiss after selecting an option

Comment: I updated my code like you asked but `final AlertDialog levelDialog = builder.create();` is giving the error `builder cannot be resolved` I also edited my code on the site so you can check and also changed the `getApplicationContext()` to `MyActivity.this`

Comment: That's because you needed to keep it after you set up your `builder` as you had it, just declare and initialize it there, sorry for the confusion. Also, please don't change your OP or it will become useless for others

Comment: I'm sorry for changing original post, will put it back to original. But I don't get where to declare and initialize

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30860/discussion-between-codemagic-and-mxx)